Setup a domino test mailserver without having access to Notes client
We have a client using an HCL Domino mail server with our application, which connects via POP3. I need to reproduce a bug, so I set up a Domino test server on AWS Marketplace: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-ptjcau2wktk2m. I followed these deployment steps: https://opensource.hcltechsw.com/domino-on-aws/deployment-steps/.
I successfully started the server and enabled POP3 using the commands domino console and load pop3. However, I cannot create a user or log in to the web interface. I attempted to log in with MYDOMAIN\admin and admin@MYDOMAIN using the password set during setup, but without success.
Running show users and show iNetUsers in the Domino console returns no results. All user creation guides require Domino® Administrator, which I don't have access to.
I need a dummy test user, either admin or any other user, to retrieve emails via POP3. Any idea on how to achieve this without using Notes would be much appreciated. I have zero experience with Lotus (not even as a user) and it's driving me nuts.
Update: I managed to get it runing. But I only with the Domino Administrator :(

If it was me, I'd simply download and install a demo Notes client - they install pretty painlessly, I've had to use them for development - and use that.

I was able to organize access to a domino server and could reproduce my issue. However unfortunately I don't have a general way to do it :( The demo notes client seems to be discontinued as far as I can tell. Getting access to a demo requires going through a reseller and is quite complicate.
